# How to add circular layout to relative layout dynamically?

Tags: android

I have an xml which contains circular layout and a relative layout like below

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.github.andreilisun.circular_layout.CircularLayout
            android:id="@+id/circular_layout"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I am filling my circular layout dynamically through text views,my layout does not show any thing. Actually i am unable to show latest circular view. Any idea on how to add my circular layout to relative layout through code?

Comment: [MR. Andreilisun](https://github.com/andreilisun/Circular-Layout/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/github/andreilisun/circularlayout/MainActivity.java) has already gave solution for your requirement.

Comment: I have done that and its working fine but at the end i have to add the whole circular view inside some realtive layout for my needs

Comment: adding whole circle view through programmatically ?

Comment: Yes adding whole circular view to relative layout programmatically

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have done with a simple example.

> 1. create xml with

```
<RelativeLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/relative_layout_id"/>
```

> 2. implement in .jav file

```
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_id);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(220, 220);
        CircularLayout circularLayout = new CircularLayout(this);
        circularLayout.setCapacity(12);
        circularLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        for (i in 0 until 12) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText(i.toString());
            circularLayout.addView(textView);
            //circularLayout.invalidate();
        }

        relativeLayout.addView(circularLayout);
```

**Note: If you want to add Margin, padding, parent_center etc, to the CircularView. Make changes to the layoutParams as per your requirement**